# Is this a valid way of showing these matrices are a basis for $M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given a set of $2\times 2$ matrices and am asked if the set forms a basis for $M_{22}$. Now, I know to show this, I must show that the set spans $M_{22}$ and is linearly independent.

Show that $\begin{pmatrix}
3&6\\
3&-6\\
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
-1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
0&-8\\
-12&-4\\
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
-1&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$ forms a basis for $M_{22}$.

This implies we must show the system $$k_1M_1+k_2M_2+k_3M_3+k_4M_4=\vec{0}$$ possesses only the trivial solution.

Then we must also show any $M_{22}$ matrix $B$ can be written as a linear combination of $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4$ $$k_1M_1+k_2M_2+k_3M_3+k_4M_4=B$$

My approach: $$k_1(3,6,3,-6)+k_2(0,-1,-1,0)+k_3(0,-8,-12,-4)+k_4(1,0,-1,2) = \vec{0}$$Form the $4\times4$ matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}
3&6&3&-6\\
0&-1&-1&0\\
0&-8&-12&-4\\
1&0&-1&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I say we can simultaneously show linear independence and spanning by showing that the determinant of the above matrix is nonzero. My question is: Is this method valid?

Comment: Sure - why not?

Comment: What you did is allowed because $M_{22}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^4$, and "linearizing" is an isomorphism. This is easy to prove, and allows you to treat matrices like "straight" vectors (as far as linear algebra concepts like basis/dimension/dependence are concerned).